# How To Display List of Sites One At A Time

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am looking for a way to display a list of websites one at a time from a URL list.  I'm fine with a very manual solution, I found an AJAX solution where each "page" is displayed in a tab but it is very heavy because if I have 50 pages I want users to page through one at a time, this solution essentially pulls all 50 pages onto the one page.  Do you know of a framework which does the same thing but only loads one page at a time?  Thank you very much for the advice and help.  Here is the site I found - http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/

Comment: Exactly what do you want to display? Just the URL? Or a rendered thumbnail? I don't quite understand the question...

Comment: The site itself.  So lets say I have a list of sites (facebook.com, google.com, microsoft.com).  I want to display the sites one at a time using next/previous links similar to what this site is doing.  http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/  The problem with their solution is it is pulling all the content onto one page and I want to take users to each page one at a time so it isn't such a heavy page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the URLs into an array and then create a 'next' button that loads the next url into a div; replacing the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

do you require doing this will javascript?
might be easier to curl the pages using php, then echo this returned data as an eval-able array into the html. Then allow user to alter which part of the returned array you are looking at using a next and prev button.

if you pre-load each one it will be heavy as you have noted.

Comment: I'm not tied to any one method (thanks for asking).  If you know of a way to do it with example code I agree a PHP solution would be great and I have that capability/environment.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is screaming for AJAX. With proper AJAX calls, you would only load a page once it has actually been selected by tab. Any previous page loaded into the area would need to be dumped. You shouldn't actually need to physically switch tabs if you're using the src attribute of an iframe, simply changing the src and forcing it to refresh itself should accomplish the trick. If you are performing a screen scrape through a remote web service, then you could simply use jQuery/AJAX to rewrite the innerHTML of the panel in question.